# valid image location not displaying the image

Tags: php, html, mysql, image

For the first time i am transferring my work on php and mysql from localhost to a free web host called 1freehosting.I am having  a problem regarding displaying profile image.While it works on localhost but for some some reason the image is not being displayed when entered through my own domain.

To check the location i separately echoed the image location and i get the exact location of my image

> `<?php echo 'image location : '.$data->imagelocation; ?>` //prints image location :
>   /home/u377815502/public_html/main/practice/users/1702f756/profile
>   image/P_20151210_191940_BF.jpg  which is my image location

but image is not showing inside my image tag

```
   <img style='width:200px;height=200px;' src='<?php echo $data->imagelocation; ?>' title='<?php echo $loggerData->username; ?>'>
```

what might be the reason for that ? how i can solve this issue ? thanks :)

Comment: What does the printed img-element look like?

Comment: it's small icon which we generally get when image is not showing properly

Comment: If you look at the source code..

Comment: i think you didn't complete the comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because your image path `/home/u377815502/...` is a *server side* path. Put that in the address bar of your web browser and it won't work.

You need to echo out a `http://...` URL that a browser can use.

From looking at the path, it probably needs to be something like:

```
http://[your-app-hostname]/main/practice/users/1702f756/profile image/P_20151210_191940_BF.jpg
```

Or you could just make it a relative URI. Here's some rough code that may help:

```
<?php
// This appears to be your www root. Change it if needed
$wwwRoot = "/home/u377815502/public_html";

// This strips out the server-side www root from your image path, leaving a relative path
$imageUri = str_replace($wwwRoot, "", $data->imagelocation);
?>

<img src='<?php echo $imageUri ?>'/>
```

Comment: That's because `$data->imagelocation` still starts with `/home/u377/...`. You  need to look at your source code (the generated HTML code in the browser) and you'll see why the URL doesn't work.

Comment: @AL-zami if you're running this off your own local machine, the syntax is `http://localhost/folder/file.php`. I doubt that `$data` is "localhost" or "example.com" here. You need to append to it.

Comment: still not clear.... i omitted one backslash and tried this ..similar result <?php echo 'http:/'.$data->imagelocation; ?>

Comment: @AL-zami that is absolutely not going to work. Before you do this in PHP, maybe just play with the URL in your browser? First get to a point where you can load the profile image in your browser, manually. Then look at that URL, it'll help you understand what needs to happen here.

Comment: @AL-zami also see my updated answer. The rough code at the end should help you understand what needs to change.

Comment: by host name you mean domain name ..in my case ezphp.tk right ?

Comment: @AL-zami Yes. Same thing.

Comment: why i need the $imguri variable  ..?in your case you are not replacing anything .. i have fromatted the image location .in view source it looks like this ..not working still :(  http://ezphp.tk/home/u377815502/public_html/main/practice/users/1702f756/profile image/P_20151210_191940_BF.jpg

Comment: @AL-zami It's all about _removing_ the part of your server-side path that the browser shouldn't even know about. `/home/u377815502/public_html` needs to be stripped. See my updated answer, it's a bit simpler.

Comment: @AL-zami with the code I've provided, you'll get this: `<img src='/main/practice/users/1702f756/profile image/P_20151210_191940_BF.jpg'/>`. If you are loading that from your `ezphp.tk` domain, it works! Check it out: http://ezphp.tk/main/practice/users/1702f756/profile%20image/P_20151210_191940_BF.jpg

Comment: @AL-zami awesome glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

I think that your "**localhost**" (You can configure this Path on apache config..) **start** inside of **public_html**, So try this.

```
 <img style='width:200px;height=200px;' src='localhost/main/practice/users/1702f756/profile image/P_20151210_191940_BF.jpg' >
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. This is working.

```
<?php

// This appears to be your www root. Change it if needed
$wwwRoot = "/home/u377815502/public_html/";

// This replaces your local system path to your absolute domain path
$imageUri = str_replace($wwwRoot, "http://[YOURDOMAIN.COM]/", $data->imagelocation);
?>

<img src='http://<?php echo $imageUri  ?>'/>
```

Please note this will load image only on your web host.